# Linq query to group by fields with counts

Tags: c#, linq

So Ive been trying to get this linq query to properly query but it is just counting by the records and not repeated entries.

```
var groupedList = from x in WarningList
group WarningList by new {etlTraceMessage.Message}
into grouped
select new {grouped.Key.Message, Count = grouped.Count()};
```

Im trying to get a result set like...

```
15 - Missing ID
 4 - Invalid use of term
 1 - Package missing
```

But its only querying as a count of records and not how many per each type etc.

```
20 - Missing ID
```

Warninglist is just an observablecollection class with a few properties

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is your classes for `WarningList`, but let me assume that it has a `Message` property and you want to group your list by this property:

```
public class Warn
{
    public string Message {get; set;}
    //other properties
}
```

If so - you can easily group your list like this:

```
var groupedList = WarningList
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Message)
                    .Select(g => new {Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
```

Or if you want another sintax:

```
var groupedList = from x in WarningList
                    group x by x.Message into grouped
                    select new { Key = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count()};
```

In your approach you tried to group by a composite key (which is unnecessary) but used some different local variable - not linked to your query (`etlTraceMessage.Message`). But if you will need it later:

```
var groupedList = from x in WarningList
                    group x by new { x.Message } into grouped
                    select new { Key = grouped.Key.Message, Count = grouped.Count()};
```

And just in case - [msdn has a lot of examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384063(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I looked over the msdn link but didnt see anything on multiple groupby fields. Id like to add the extra group by as "    etlTraceMessage.Level == EtlTraceLevel.Warning"

Comment: I am not sure that understand you completely... If you want to group by 2 properties - Message and Level you can do it like this: `group x by new {Message = x.Message, Level = x.Level}`